# How to change background color of SVG with pattern

Tags: svg

Im trying to change a background color of svg rect that is filled with a pattern.

This is my simplified rect svg with a defined pattern:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" class="border">
    <defs>
       <pattern id="diagonalHatch" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:8" />
       </pattern>
    </defs>

    <g>
       <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to change the rect background color (color will be changed in runtime) and not affect the pattern?

So for example I need a rect with yellow, orange, red background and blue diagonal hatch.

Comment: add another rect behind that one or change the pattern.

Comment: thank you! that was easy and simple. I updated my question with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution proposed by @Robert Longson.

Just add another rect behind.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" class="border">
  <defs>
     <pattern id="diagonalHatch" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(45 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="20" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:8" />
      </pattern>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
    <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#diagonalHatch)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```